# Efficient way to check a prime of Prime digits

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-mathematics

I was trying to solve a question on number theory. It says, given a range (**start**, **end** $ \le 10^{15}$ and **end - start** $ \le 10^9$), how many prime digit prime numbers exist? Generating prime digits numbers is easy but to check whether this number is prime, it runs out of time. I discarded numbers ending with $2$ or $5$, still a large number to go through primality test. So is there an efficient way to do primality test for prime digits prime number.

**Note**: I tried with sieve but failed for large number typically $\ge10^7$.

Comment: I assume that a "prime digit" number means a number that, in base $10$, is written using only $\{2,3,5,7\}$?  If so, I really can't imagine that there is a primality test that works especially well on this category.

Comment: In that case how can we efficiently compute the solution of above stated problem?

Comment: Those numbers are all quite small.  $15$ digits is well within the range of rapid computation by standard methods.  That is to say, this is a programming problem, not a math problem.

Comment: Or does it mean a prime with a prime number of decimal digits?  That's how I understood it before reading lulu's comment.

Comment: If I have $10^5$ numbers to check and I go with $\sqrt{n}$ primality test solution then it's not a better approach

Comment: I think I need to test with  Millar Rabin approach.

Comment: @DebasisJana In fact, This should be considerably more efficient than trial division. A good alternative is the BPSW - test, for which no counter-example is known and  upto $10^{16}$ , it should be realiable. It is claimed that upto $2^{64}$, there is no counter-example. Anyway, for the range you have given, the method should be $100$% correct.

Comment: What exactly was the problem with pre-sieving ? If you want to check a large number of positive integers, this is usually the first step.